# Extract RGB Values From UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, rgb, uicolor

I have seen people do this in objective-c, but I am having trouble with this in swift. I have gotten the color of a pixel from a picture, but now I need to take the individual red, green, and blue values. Here is what I have (h, w, and rgb are integers and image.getPixelColor(CGPoint) returns a UIColor):

```
 xArry[h][w][rgb] = image.getPixelColor(CGPoint(x: w, y: h))
```

How do I change this UIColor into the red, green, and blue values? Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can convert UIColor to CIColor and then extract the color components from it as follow:

Update: **Xcode 8.3.2 • Swift 3.1**

```
extension UIColor {
    var coreImageColor: CIColor {
        return CIColor(color: self)
    }
    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let coreImageColor = self.coreImageColor
        return (coreImageColor.red, coreImageColor.green, coreImageColor.blue, coreImageColor.alpha)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let myColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1, blue: 0.25, alpha: 0.5)
let myCIColor = myColor.coreImageColor
let greencomponent = myColor.components.green
let myColorComponents = myColor.components
print(myColorComponents.red)   // 0.5
print(myColorComponents.green) // 1.0
print(myColorComponents.blue)  // 0.25
print(myColorComponents.alpha) // 0.5
```

---

---

You can also use the function getRed() and create an extension to extract the components as follow but the result would be optional:

```
extension UIColor {
    typealias RGBA = (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
    var rgba: RGBA? {
        var (r, g, b, a): RGBA = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        return getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a) ? (r,g,b,a) : nil
    }
    var r: CGFloat? {
        var red: CGFloat = .zero
        return getRed(&red, green: nil, blue: nil, alpha: nil) ? red : nil
    }
    var g: CGFloat? {
        var green: CGFloat = .zero
        return getRed(nil, green: &green, blue: nil, alpha: nil) ? green : nil
    }
    var b: CGFloat? {
        var blue: CGFloat = .zero
        return getRed(nil, green: nil, blue: &blue, alpha: nil) ? blue : nil
    }
    var a: CGFloat? {
        var alpha: CGFloat = .zero
        return getRed(nil, green: nil, blue: nil, alpha: &alpha) ? alpha : nil
    }
}
```

---

Usage

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 1, blue: 0.25, alpha: 0.5)
if let components = color.rgba {
    print(components.red)   // 0.5
    print(components.green) // 1.0
    print(components.blue)  // 0.25
    print(components.alpha) // 0.5
}

print(color.r ?? "nil")   // 0.5
print(color.g ?? "nil") // 1.0
print(color.b ?? "nil")  // 0.25
print(color.a ?? "nil") // 0.5
```

Comment: Why create 4 `CIColor` instances? Create one, assign it to a variable, and get the 4 components from it.

Comment: Can someone explain exactly how that works? I'm guessing "components" is a tuple that contains the elements. But whats the rest? Some kind of function-ish?

Comment: I got it. Its "Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function" from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID232

Comment: @everlof this is called a read-only computed property. It returns a tuple of 4 elements. It has a getter but it doesn't have a setter and to simplify declaration you can omit the getter. More info here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Comment: I'm not sure if something changed in Swift 2.2, but `CoreImage.CIColor(color:)` doesn't return an optional, and `getRed(_,green:,blue:,alpha:)` can, so I'm going to edit your answer to make it more correct. :)

Comment: @NiñoScript thats correct CIColor initializer used to return an optional and in the getRed case I was returning clear color in case of failure which depends on personal preference.

Comment: I don't think it's about personal preference, `getRed:green:blue:alpha` returns false if there was an error when converting to the sRGB color space; so you were hiding an error, or making the clear color components look like an "error" color, which has the same problem as NULL references: it's "The Billion Dollar Mistake" all over again. I think it's much better now.

Comment: But if someone needs the old behavior, just call `let components = myColor.components ?? (red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)`

Answer (score 21):

for UIColor you can just use getRed method:

```
let yourColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 184/255, blue: 48/255, alpha: 1.0)
var r: CGFloat = 0, g: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
yourColor.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
print("red: \(r), green: \(g), blue: \(b)")
```

Comment: Agree. This is the best way so far to extract RGBA values. Excellent option if you need to modify one of them. Votes up!

Answer (score 4):

You can use CGColorGetComponents to get array of color of a CGColor (not tested in swift3)

```
const CGFloat *_components = CGColorGetComponents(yourUIColor.CGColor);
    CGFloat red     = _components[0];
    CGFloat green = _components[1];
    CGFloat blue   = _components[2];
    CGFloat alpha = _components[3];
```

You can find also number of color components of that color with

```
CGColorGetNumberOfComponents
```

You have to verify number of components before get values. Gray color has 2 components (grey & alpha), rgb colors have 4 components: R, G, B, A

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGColorGetNumberOfComponents

Comment: Don't assume there are 4 color components.

Comment: This is for RGB color (except white & black that is grey color?). Normally, a RGB has 4 components: R, G, B, Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but this should work. Just found it:

```
   xArry[h][w][rgb] = Int(image.getPixelColor(CGPoint(x: w, y: h)).CIColor.red())
```