# CIColor to UIColor -> CIColor not defined for the UIColor UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, color-space

I'm trying to implement CIColor from rgb-hex colorspace as follows:

```
    let bottomColor = UIColor.init(red: 235/255, green: 250/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).ciColor
```

However, I keep on hitting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -CIColor not defined for
>   the UIColor UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.921569 0.980392 1 1; need to
>   first convert colorspace.'

I'm not sure what this means. How to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this will work:

```
let uiColor = UIColor.init(red: 235.0/255.0, green: 250.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let bottomColor = CIColor(color: uiColor)
```

You can also add an extension on UIColor:

```
extension UIColor {
    var coreImageColor: CIColor {
        return CIColor(color: self)
    }
    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let color = coreImageColor
        return (color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha)
    }
}
```

And then call it via:

```
let bottomColor = UIColor.init(red: 235.0/255.0, green: 250.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).coreImageColor
```

The answer and explanation for which I found [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532564/extract-rgb-values-from-uicolor).