# Converting UIColor (extended range sRGB) to CIColor

Tags: swift, colors, swift3, ios10, uicolor

When I run the following Swift 3.0.1 line on iOS 10.2.1:

```
let color = CIColor(color: UIColor(hue: 0.72, saturation: 1.00, brightness: 0.78, alpha: 1));
```

I get the following error:

> '*** -CIColor not defined for the UIColor UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; need to first convert colorspace.'

According to the documentation:

> The color object. The color information represented by this object is in an RGB colorspace. On applications linked for iOS 10 or later, the color is specified in an extended range sRGB color space. On earlier versions of iOS, the color is specified in a device RGB colorspace.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621931-init

What is the appropriate syntax to get the `CIColor` from this `UIColor` now that the `CIColor` is in the device RGB colorspace and the `UIColor` is in the extended sRGB colorspace?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816422/cicolor-to-uicolor-cicolor-not-defined-for-the-uicolor-uiextendedsrgbcolorspa

Comment: I looked at that, but unfortunately that post is going from CIColor -> UIColor, whereas I am doing the opposite: going from UIColor -> CIColor.

Comment: your code runs fine as it is for me Xcode 8.2.1 Swift 3.0.2

Comment: @LeoDabus Not only it runs fine for me, but doing `UIColor(hue: 0.72, saturation: 1.00, brightness: 0.78, alpha: 1).ciColor` is what actually causes the error for me.

Comment: @BrunoPhilipe from the ciColor property docs **This property throws an exception if the color object was not initialized with a Core Image color.**

Comment: try `UIColor(ciColor: CIColor(color: UIColor(hue: 0.72, saturation: 1.00, brightness: 0.78, alpha: 1))).ciColor`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the feedback provided in the comments, I found the source of the error:

Later in the method, I called .ciColor on an instance of UIColor. This fails because the UIColor instance was not first created by CIColor.

It appears as though the following conditions hold:

- UIColor => CIColor: must be initialized by the CIColor(color: UIColor instance) constructor
- CIColor => UIColor => CIColor: .ciColor property available.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Jake Chasan the CIColor instance must be initialized with a UIColor instance. So this swift code worked for me:

```
func colorToRGB(uiColor: UIColor) -> CIColor
{
    return CIColor(color: uiColor)
}
```