# Convert UIColor to 24 bit value

Tags: ios, bluetooth, swift3, bit, uicolor

I have a bluetooth device (led light) to which I can send different commands to. By now everything works fine and all the commands work. Now I want to send a custom command. The documentation says the following:
[0X99] + [24 bit colorimetric value (R=?,G=?,B=?)] + [8bit speed value] + ...

Now I don't know how to get the 24 bit colorimetric value from an UIColor.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532564/extract-rgb-values-from-uicolor). This shows how to convert uicolor to its rgb component values.The values are returned as a float ratio. You can convert this ration to base 8 color and send to the device.

Hope this helps.